# Filter List in Html.EditorFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I was just wondering if there was a way to apply a filter to the @Html.EditorFor() when using it for a collection.

Lets say I have the following code:
**EditorTemplates/Foo**

```
@model Foo
@Html.EditorFor(f = f.FooDetails)
```

**EditorTemplates/FooDetail**

```
@model FooDetail
@Html.LabelFor(f => f.Group)

@Html.LabelFor(f => f.Name)
@Html.Editorfor(f => f.Name)
```

My first thought would be to do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(f = f.FooDetails.Where(x => x.Group == group)
```

However, after crossing my fingers while trying it out, I was reminded that life is not always simple and it gave back an InvalidOperationException due to "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Any suggestions on how I would properly approach the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.EditorFor` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that allows you to specify additional view data. You can pass the criteria through this parameter.

So your EditorFor becomes this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(f = f.FooDetails, new { Group = group})
```

And your editor template* becomes this:

```
@model FooDetail

@if ((string)ViewData["Group"] == Model.Group) {
    @Html.LabelFor(f => f.Group)
    @Html.LabelFor(f => f.Name)
    @Html.Editorfor(f => f.Name)
}
```

*this assumes group is a string, change type as required

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it would be to declare a separate variable outside of the `Html.EditorFor`.

Instead of using `@Html.EditorFor(f = f.FooDetails.Where(x => x.Group == group))`, you could say:

```
    var filteredFooDetails = Model.FooDetails.Where(x => x.Group == group));
    @Html.EditorFor(f => filteredFooDetails);
```

*EDIT*

As a comment mentioned, this will break model binding. To be able to get the value out on the other end, your controller method would have to accept both a model, and another argument for `filteredFooDetails`. Using the property on the model object might lead to confusion on another developers part. How would they know that `FooDetails` on this particular `model` object may only be a subset of the whole?

On the other hand, if none of that matters, you can also just make the variable name `fooDetails` instead of `filteredFooDetails` and model binding will pick it up.

Comment: Doing this causes the naming to be incorrect and you lose the model binding on the controller side

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this question while trying to solve a similar problem. I needed to create a grid ordered by categories while filtering the main model collection by category to appear under each category heading. I created an editor template for the entire view model and call Html.DisplayForModel() from the view.

Page view model

```
namespace GoodHousekeeping.MVC.Models
{
  public class ViewIngredientPageModel
  {
    public IEnumerable<ViewIngredientModel> ViewIngredientModels { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewIngredientCategoryModel> 
                          ViewIngredientCategoryModels { get; set; }
  }
}
```

View Model

```
namespace GoodHousekeeping.MVC.Models
{
  public class ViewIngredientModel
  {
    public int? IngredientId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ingredient Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int IngredientCategoryId { get; set; }

    #region navigation

    public ViewIngredientCategoryModel IngredientCategory { get; set; }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Main view

```
@model GoodHousekeeping.MVC.Models.ViewIngredientPageModel

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

EditorTemplate - this is where we're working on the whole view model and doing the filtering. The file name is ViewIngredientPageModel.cshtml in shared/editortemplates folder. I'm calling a standard editorfor template for each item to appear under the category headers.

```
@model GoodHousekeeping.MVC.Models.ViewIngredientPageModel
@foreach (var category in Model.ViewIngredientCategoryModels)
{
    <p>@category.IngredientCategoryName</p>
    var category1 = category;
    var viewIngredientModels = (from i in Model.ViewIngredientModels
                 where i.IngredientCategoryId == category1.IngredientCategoryId
                 select i);

    @Html.DisplayFor(m => viewIngredientModels)
}
```